# On button click switch to new layout xml file, using buttons now but how do I use fragments?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, bluetooth

I am creating a Bluetooth app that requires a log in and/or sign up. I use a button click to switch to new layout xml file, but I need to not use buttons and figure out how to use fragments! When I have a button on the second page that gets clicked it crashes the app. Help :(

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.chirp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() ;
        bluetooth.setName("Chirp Bluetooth");

        String status; {
            if (bluetooth != null)
            {

                if (bluetooth.isEnabled())
                {
                    String mydeviceaddress = bluetooth.getAddress();
                    String mydevicename = bluetooth.getName();
//                  String state = bluetooth.getState();
//                  status = mydevicename + ":" + mydeviceaddress + ":" + state;
                }
                else
                {
                    status = "Bluetooth is not Enabled.";
                }
                }
//          Toast.makeText(this, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }   

//        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
//
//        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
//        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
//        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//       
        Button quickfindbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.qfbutton);
        quickfindbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){

            }
        });

        Button loginbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);               

        };

        });


    Button signupbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    signupbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            setContentView(R.layout.signupscreen);
        }
         });

//    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
//    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
//      public void onClick(View v){
//          setContentView(R.layout.devicepage);
//      }
//       });




    }

    public void showToast(String message) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        toast.show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           return true;

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true; 
    }

//    public void newMessage(View v){
//      Intent intent = new Intent(this,loginscreen.class);
//      startActivity(intent);
//    }
    }
```

Comment: Post logcat error trace.

Comment: You cannot set new setContentView onclick `setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);`, may be you have to learn little more basics in Android.

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView()` should be in `onCreate()` method within first few lines. Otherwise it will not work. If you need to change the layout after click on the button what you can do is, use `SharedPreferences`.

Check the saved item in `shared Preferences` before and then use `setContentView()` method in `onCreate()`. Inside the button `onClick ()` method save the wanted layout in `SharedPreferences`. Then write the code to restart the application.

Comment: a second onCreate() ? Inside the already                          

'protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);'
?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

And also check if your second activity is registered in the manifest.xml.